# Is there any advantage to declare map as Map<String, Object> as oppose to just Map

Tags: java, generics

Besides ensuring key is a String as compile type, is there any other advantage to it? or can it be left out? The value i am storing can be of multiple types

Comment: `Map<String, Object>` is a good start.  Can you think of a way to make `Object` a little more precise?  Surely you're doing _something_ to the Object, calling some method.

Comment: You _shouldn't_ store values of multiple types in the same map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declaraing a `Map` without generic type information is *deprecated* and most IDEs are generating warning here. This is important left alone, even if it is `Map<Object, Object>`. Also ensuring the key is a `String` at compile time is actually quite a lot.

Technically the types are erased during compilation so there is no advantage while running the code. But again - since Java 5 you should always include generic type information.

Answer (score 2):

The benefits of using `Map<String, Object>` are mainly code readability. 
It is easier for other developers to read your code and also saves you some casting operations.
After compilation however the generics are removed so it does not have any real impact on the application. 
You can also see: [reason generics were introduced in java 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545141/reason-generics-were-introduced-in-java-5)

Comment: Mainly type safety actually, with readability as a side benefit.